# Putting Stickers on Top MacBook Pro Lid - Recommendations

Tags: macbook-pro

I've got a new MacBook from the company I work for. I have some nice stickers I want to put on the lid. However I am worried about removing them. Is there  skin/layer apply before so I can remove them all easily if I have to return it?

Comment: Is not the MacBook Pro elegant enough as is, why defile its beauty with stickers!?

Answer (score 2):

If you get something like a [Macbook Vinyl Decal Sticker](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004YVH6HG) it should stay on very well but those are also very easy to remove, and people say no reside is left on the machine. So if you get one of those no layer/skin is needed.

[image: Vinyl sticker]

Though if you want a skin, [DBrand Macbook Skins, Wraps and Decals](https://dbrand.com/macbook-skins) are the best looking and quality.

[image: dbrand skin]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest getting a [speck case](http://www.speckproducts.com/apple/macbook-cases.html) for your MacBook, or something similar.

[image: Speck case]

Comment: Thanks!.  I thought about it. But they are heavy and make my computer bulky. So I was looking for alternative to them.